# PHPUnitTest is missing the file_managed table?

Tags: 8, testing, files

My PHPUnit test is throwing an error saying that my `file_managed` test database table does not exist. What module do I need to include for that test table to get created? I would think it should be the `file` module, but I've already got that listed in my $modules array.

This is a Kernel test and I've been trying to fill up the modules array with everything I can think of that might actually get that table created.

```
  public static $modules = [
    'system',
    'path',
    'user',
    'file',
    'file_test',
    'node',
    'field',
    'media_entity',
    'entity',
    'image',
    'graphql',
    'graphql_core',
    'custom_graphql_file_upload',
    'custom_graphql_field'
  ];
```

Here's the error:

```
Invalid GraphQL query. Errors: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'contenta.test87607590file_managed' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uuid, langcode, uid, filename, uri, filemime, filesize, status, created, changed) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array
```

I'm trying to test a `graphql` file upload to make sure the file entity gets created as expected. I have a lot more tests I want to write and lot more that needs to be solved with multi-part/form data, etc, but I need to figure this out first I think.

Here's the full test
https://github.com/justinlevi/graphql_custom_file_upload/blob/feature/PHPUnitTest_WIP/tests/src/Kernel/MutationFileUploadTest.php

All other code posted as well on the WIP branch.

Answer (score 5):

Ugh... Forgot to install the entitySchema.

This is how to do it in the setup method

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->installConfig('system');
    $this->installConfig('graphql');
    $this->installConfig('file');
    $this->installConfig('image');
    $this->installConfig('user');
    $this->installEntitySchema('user');
    $this->installEntitySchema('file');


    Role::load(RoleInterface::AUTHENTICATED_ID)
      ->grantPermission('execute graphql requests')
      ->grantPermission('create media')
      ->grantPermission('view media')
      ->grantPermission('access content')
      ->grantPermission('bypass node access')
      ->grantPermission('create url aliases')
      ->save();
  }
```